# How to hide WebView content behind the ProgressDialog in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

How can I hide everything behind the ProgressDialog and only show them only after getting completely loaded? Actually I need a white screen behind the dialog above my WebView content while the progress is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the layout you want to hide an ID in the xml files, then find that layout in your activity/fragment, and then you can use '.setVisibility(View.GONE);" to hide it as you want, or '.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" to show it.

Then simply hide it by default, and when you got your data, show it.