# How to change the activity background color while a progress dialog is on

Tags: android, progressdialog

The title says essentially everything, i looked at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html 
but i didnt find anything that seemed to be what im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove that light gray background color then use below code with your progress dialog:

```
mProgressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHI‌​ND);
```

And if you want to change that color, then use another layout on the top of the background but behind the Progress Dialog until dialog is open. That layout will contain whatever color you want to show there.

You can also choose [alpha](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#ALPHA) property for that layout which will make background look transparent.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, i found something that is probably better in another thread, pretty much hides the layout behind.
[How to hide WebView content behind the ProgressDialog in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415251/how-to-hide-webview-content-behind-the-progressdialog-in-android-studio)